# How to draw a rectangle in an image which will only be shown when mouse moves over certain location in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

In openCV, i need to do the following: when user moves mouse over certain location, a rectangle will be shown over the image but when he moves cursor out of the location , the rectangle will be gone.

i am new to opencv, i can draw rectangle on mouse move event but i can't figure out how to undo the drawing after the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the region of the original image that will be drawn over by the rectangle in a separate `Mat`.  When the cursor is removed, copy the stored region back to its original location.

Comment: If this solves your problem, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. ;)